# Ventura upgrade causes causes color problems with external display

Tags: display, color, ventura

I've been using my MacBook with an external display attached. Typically, I use it with the laptop closed, and the display on.

After upgrading to Ventura, I noticed something off about my external display's colors. The best I can describe it is that the yellow and green colors appear too "greenish". Interestingly, the problem resolves itself as soon as I open the lid of my laptop which is attached to the monitor.

Here are the display settings if they are helpful.

[image: display settings]

Comment: I'm having this same problem. I put facebook side by side with Monterey in PBP and got bluish in Monterey and greenish on Ventura. Same color profile.

Comment: it's like dirty, aged, old paper.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this question after having this same issue with the same exact monitor. It seems turning off the High Dynamic Range setting fixed the issue.

Comment: Is there a way to use the monitor with High Dynamic Range though?